# How to add lines with specific pattern in a file at first of all the other lines?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file like this:

```
@asdsad-asddad  
234  
232  
343  
@hjkkhjk-dsfsd  
234234  
64564  
43  
4545  
563  
121  
@sdfdfs-fdhhg  
2334464  
567  
45  
787  
@dfsd-tyu  
4556
```

I want to print the rows with @ at first of the other rows for each section. An output like this:

```
@asdsad-asddad 234  
@asdsad-asddad 232  
@asdsad-asddad 343    
@hjkkhjk-dsfsd 234234  
@hjkkhjk-dsfsd 64564  
@hjkkhjk-dsfsd 43  
@hjkkhjk-dsfsd 4545  
@hjkkhjk-dsfsd 563  
@hjkkhjk-dsfsd 121    
@sdfdfs-fdhhg 2334464  
@sdfdfs-fdhhg 567  
@sdfdfs-fdhhg 45  
@sdfdfs-fdhhg 787       
@dfsd-tyu 4556
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Vahid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep a variable with the current section and print each line after it, eg.

```
awk '/^@/ { section = $0; next } { print section $0 }' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `awk` could you please try following.

```
awk -v RS="@" 'FNR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1,$i}}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation of code:***

```
awk -v RS="@" '          ##Starting awk program here and mentioning RS as @ here.
FNR>1{                   ##Checking condition if FNR>1 then do following.
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){    ##Starting a for loop from i=2 to till value of NF here.
    print $1,$i          ##Printing value of $1 and current field value.
  }                      ##Closing block for, for loop here.
}                        ##Closing bock for FNR>1 condition here.
'  Input_file            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @Vahid, Could you please check this solution if this helped you?